# How to arrange the automaton's states on an arbitrary path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I need to locate some states of an automaton on a circular path, is which neither easy nor precise to do with right, above, left, left above and the other typical options for relative replacement.

**Is there any way to introduce an arbitrary path for locating the states, instead of the typical grid-like formations?...**

Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial,accepting, initial where=above] (s_00)   {$s_{00}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_23) [above = of s_00]  {$s_{23}$};
   \node[state,accepting] (s_03) [left = of s_23]  {$s_{03}$};
   \node[state,accepting] (s_02) [above = of s_03]  {$s_{02}$};
   \node[state] (s_10) [right = of s_00]  {$s_{10}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_22) [left = of s_00]  {$s_{22}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_13) [left of = s_22]  {$s_{13}$};
   \node[state,accepting] (s_01) [left of = s_13]  {$s_{01}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_14)  [below of = s_01] {$s_{14}$};
   \node[state,accepting] (s_04) [below of = s_14]  {$s_{04}$};
   \node[state,accepting] (s_11)  [below of = s_04] {$s_{11}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_20)  [below = of s_22] {$s_{20}$};
   \node[state,accepting] (s_21) [below of = s_20]  {$s_{21}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_12) [below of = s_21]  {$s_{12}$}; 
   \node[state] (s_24) [below of = s_13]  {$s_{24}$};

   \path[->] 
    (s_00) edge [out=340, in=270] node {$a$} (s_11)
           edge node {$b$} (s_22)
    (s_01) edge node {$a$} (s_14)
           edge node {$b$} (s_24)
    (s_02) edge [in=180, out=180, swap] node {$a$} (s_14)
           edge node {$b$} (s_23)
    (s_03) edge [out=180, in=180, swap] node {$a$} (s_11)
           edge node {$b$} (s_22)
    (s_04) edge node {$a$} (s_14)
           edge node {$b$} (s_24)
    (s_10) edge node {$a$} (s_21)
           edge [bend right, swap] node {$b$} (s_02)
    (s_11) edge node {$a$} (s_24)
           edge node {$b$} (s_04)
    (s_12) edge node {$a$} (s_24)
           edge [out=0, in=90] node {$b$} (s_03)
    (s_13) edge [out=0, in=0] node {$a$} (s_21)
           edge node {$b$} (s_01)
    (s_14) edge node {$a$} (s_24)
           edge node {$b$} (s_04)
    (s_20) edge node {$a$} (s_24)
           edge node {$b$} (s_22)
    (s_21) edge node {$a, b$} (s_24)
    (s_22) edge node {$a$} (s_24)
           edge node {$b$} (s_23)
    (s_23) edge [in=70, out=0] node {$a$} (s_21)
           edge node {$b$} (s_22)
    (s_24) edge [loop above] node {$a, b$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I am going to put s_24 in the middle and arrange some other states (such as s_11, s_04, s_14, s_01, s_22, s_20, s_21, s_12) around it, in a circular (or generally arbitrary) formation.

And here is the current formation:
[image]

Comment: Can you give us a clue about what tool you are using to draw the automata with?

Comment: @Thruston: Please find the update. My tool is TikZ, and I'm using automata and positioning libraries.

Comment: `Positioning` library can use two parameters: `above right = <above distance> and <right distance> of ...`. So you can *simulate* a circle with something like `above right = {2*sin(30)} and {2*(cos(30)} of s_00` or similars (of course, with `calc` library).

Comment: Please can you complete your code so it can be compiled? How is `initial`, `state` etc. defined? Presumably, you are using a library ... and presumably you are loading at least `tikz` and have some sort of class ...

Comment: Use polar coordinates with `s24` at `(0,0)`? I'm not really clear how the nodes are meant to fit into the existing diagram, though.

Comment: @cfr: Whole the stuff will be compiled with two introduced libraries, as positioning and automata, both from TikZ. Your suggestion to use polar coordinates sounds good for circular case, but not typically expandable to any kind of planar pattern to position the states.

Comment: Please edit your question to make the code you posted compilable.

Comment: @cfr: Here you go. It's compilable, now...

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. your nodes are already in some path. It is not straight, however nodes determine coordinates of path. If you like to have some particular shape of it (for example circle, ellipse) you should only accordingly determine coordinates. Is this a problem. In comment above is already suggested how to use `positioning` library. If you like to determine nodes coordinates with intersection of different lines or curves, than you should look `intersections` library.  I guess, that real problem in your case is, how to draw connection between nodes ...

Comment: @Zarko: "you should only accordingly determine coordinates": You just did paraphrased the question!!! But thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @Roboticist, so I say, that is not clear, what you asking for. That is the point of my comment. Or do you expect that someone redraw your automaton in more pretty looks? :-)

Comment: @Zarko: I do, appreciate, again due to your deep contribution :-)

Comment: Here's the problem: it is not clear how we can answer 'how do I put nodes on an arbitrary path?' except by saying 'add the nodes on the arbitrary path of your choice'. I mean, Ti*k*Z can't put them on 'an arbitrary path' under that description. It can only put them on an arbitrary path specified in some particular way which tells it what this particular path is. Ti*k*Z just knows about paths - specific paths. It can't trace arbitrary paths as such. So it isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: @cfr : Actually, my main concern was circular path (as you addressed it, deservedly). The "arbitrary" one was just based on the curiosity to have a generic solution, as you are pointing to the flaw within this kind of imagination. I think I have the answer, now... Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the graph drawing algorithms available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state,initial,accepting, initial where=above] (s_00)   {$s_{00}$}; 
   \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {0,30,60,...,330}
        \node[state] (s_\ni) [above right = {2*sin(\i)} and {2*(cos(\i)} of s_00]  {$s_{\ni}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]